# References for superfluids that are not Helium nor BEC

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, astrophysics, soft-question, superconductivity

I've seen a lot of introductory texts dealing with BEC and two-fluid-model for superfluidity (like Helium at finite temperature). Can anybody tell me some reference for other superfluids? Is the dynamics the same? I've been said something of that sort exist in astrophysics but I don't know where. 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Superconductivity can be treated as superfluidity of the Cooper pairs - pairs of electrons with integer net spin. Its condensation is not governed by BEC (it is one of the limits, though), but by Bardeen-Cooper-Schriffer mechanism, where interaction is the key. Dynamics is somewhat similar.